# What is the difference between the process in which energy converts to matter and that in which it converts to antimatter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, antimatter

What is the difference between the process in which energy converts to matter and the process in which it converts to antimatter? In colliders, for instance, is the product (either being the matter or the antimatter counterpart of a specific particle) solely a result of angular momentum conservation (given that this certain interaction isn't a CP violating one)? Or are there other factors that determine which one is produced?

Answer (score 2):

Elementary particles differ in flavour from their antiparticles, so conservation laws do, indeed, restrict whether particles or antiparticles can be produced in certain processes. (Compare, e.g., the photon, which has zero for all its flavour quantum numbers, and is *identical* to its antiparticle.)

For example, when a neutron decays, the result is a proton, an electron, and an electron antineutrino. It can't produce an antiproton because it would violate baryon number conservation. It has to produce an electron rather than a positron, to cancel out the proton's charge. The electron antineutrino cancels out the electron's lepton number.

This is a simplistic example, because in most cases conservation laws do not determine the product uniquely. Still, the principle remains; particles and their antiparticles simply have different properties. (Even in this case, a fourth-order weak process is possible, but extremely unlikely, producing an extra neutrino-antineutrino pair.)